# Apache mod_rewrite only if request does not start with '/THEMES/'

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm writing a CMS in PHP, and now I'm working at the themes feature. I have a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ index.php?m=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)/(.+)$ index.php?m=$1&p=$2
```

If I have a request to:

```
/page
```

it must load the view function of the class called page.

If I have a request to:

```
/page/test
```

it must load the view function of the class called page, with the parameter 'test'.
This all works,

But I want it to apply the RewriteRules **ONLY** if the request does **NOT** start with:

```
/THEMES/
```

So I can apply CSS styles etc...

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use an additional rule to stop the rewriting process:

```
RewriteRule ^THEMES/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ index.php?m=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)/(.+)$ index.php?m=$1&p=$2
```

Comment: Good to know you can rewrite to - to preserve a given URL/pattern

Comment: I think the first rule should start with `^/`

Comment: @Behrang No, it’s .htaccess and `RewriteRule` where the contextual path prefix is stripped before.

Answer (score 33):

Add this before your rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/THEMES/
```

Comment: This seems to only match a full url and not an url starting with `"/THEMES/"`

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^THEMES - [L]
```

That means: if the request starts with THEMES, just serve it.

Another possible solution is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

That means: do not rewrite if the request resolves to an existing file (first line) or directory (second line).

Maybe you should read the documentations, is really well written.

Comment: Are you sure that the file/directory requested exists? It seems strange to me, it works on my system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include css/js files while using url-rewriting use that tag to specify the main url.

```
< base href="http://www.your-web-site-adress.com" >
```

Then you may easily include your css/js files like that:

```
< script src="/blabla.js" >
```

it'll add base href as prefix.