# .htacess: Remove Query Strings with Exceptions in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to remove query strings everywhere except the `wp-admin` area of WordPress.

I tried this:

```
# remove query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) $1?
```

It does the job: it deletes `?m=1` from all URLs.

The problem now is that if I try to connect to the WordPress Dashboard, the CSS doesn't load, which means that the code above is affecting `wp-admin` as well.

How would you solve this?

Comment: Is there a way to say: the condition I want, /wp-admin/ must not be in URL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181792/1427878 should be exactly what you need already, a condition that prevents the following rule from doing anything, if the requested URL path started with that particular folder name.

Comment: Great, the fourth answer worked for me. I just added RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/ before the code above and everything is fine. Thank you @CBroe.
Would you please add this as an answer so I can reward it as the best answer?